# Error Handling with S4 classes

Tags: r, r-s4

I'm a newbie here.  I am trying to use S4 classes.  In some of my setting methods, I would like to take an input value and test if it is valid.  If it is valid, I would like to assign it.  If it is not valid, I would like to generate a warning that can be tested for.  Here is a simple example:

```
 setClass("foo", representation(ind = "numeric"))

 setGeneric(name="setInd<-",def=function(object,value){standardGeneric("setInd<-")})

 setReplaceMethod(f="setInd",signature="foo",
 def=function(object,value){
   if(is.numeric(value)){
     object@ind<-value;}
   else{
     warning("Foobar")
   }
    return(object)}
 )
```

This generates a warning message when I try to assign a character:

```
> thisFoo<-new("foo", ind = 2)
> thisFoo
An object of class "foo"
Slot "ind":
[1] 2


> setInd(thisFoo)<-"A"
Warning message:
In `setInd<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "A") : Foobar
> thisFoo
An object of class "foo"
Slot "ind":
[1] 2
```

But I would like to be able to test that the assignment failed.  What is a good way of doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: In this case the assignment violates the class definition and generates an error anyway; the test isn't necessary. Alternatively, use `c("foo", "numeric")` as the signature of the replacement method, and again the attempted assignment will generate an error (because there is no method matching `c("foo", "character")`). Catch the error with `tryCatch`, as Joris mentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the assignment fails, I'd return an error instead of a warning. A warning tells you that the process went through, but might give an unexpected result. In your case, the process is aborted :

```
setReplaceMethod(f="setInd",signature="foo",
 def=function(object,value){
   if(!is.numeric(value))
     stop("Foobar")

   object@ind <- value  
   return(object)}
 )
```

using `stop` allows you to use `tryCatch()` or `try()` constructs. See the relevant help pages for more information. Eg :

```
tryCatch(setInd(thisFoo)<-"A",error=function(e){print("Hello")})

> X <- try(setInd(thisFoo) <- "A")
Error in `setInd<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "A") : Foobar
> if(is(X,"try-error")) setInd(thisFoo) <- 5
> thisFoo
An object of class "foo"
Slot "ind":
[1] 5
```

If you really need to work with warnings, look at `withCallingHandlers`. Using your original code :

```
> withCallingHandlers({setInd(thisFoo)<-"A"},
+     warning = function(w) {print("Hello")})
[1] "Hello"
Warning message:
In `setInd<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "A") : Foobar
```

Mind you, this is less straightforward to use than the abovementioned options using errors.